# Violin too small for daughter?

Tags: violin

My daughter is 6 years old and taking violin in school. They recommended that they go with 1/10 or 1/8. I went with 1/8 as she is on the taller side.

Receiving the violin in the mail, this thing looks tiny. When she holds it it is *perfect* size, but it seems as though she'd grow out of it *really* quickly.

I checked a chart online and it seems like 1/4 is for 5-7 year olds.

Would it be ok to go with the larger violin for her to grow into instead of the 1/8, where I fear she will grow out of it quickly?

Thanks!

Comment: I think normally instruments that come in different sizes are rented, so when the child is too large you simply switch to the next size up with the rental company. Perhaps that is not an option for you.

Comment: Renting would have been the best way to go.

Comment: Actually *too large* is the only problem you will encounter. An instrument, which is too small just sounds weaker than necessary, while a too big one may lead to wrong posture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The important here is to have the correct size, and following a age chart is not the way to find it. Every child is different, some are small at the same age as others already grew up.

If the child can reach out their hand and close the hand around it **with a straight arm** then the violin is OK.
If when reaching the head and closing the hand the arm gets bent, the child needs a bigger violin.
If the child does not reach the head then the violin is too big.

If you are not sure between two of those possibilities then it's no big deal, it means soon you have to get a new instrument or that the instrument will fit better soon.

If it's very clear that it is too small or too big **change it**! A bad size will make the child get used to a bad position and will influence the tuning and ergonomy in a bad way.

Comment: I think you get no notification when another user writes an answere to the same question so i write this comment to inform you about the answere of @Dave Ingledew.

Comment: That answer is now deleted. But it raised (strongly) the issue of possible improper use of a copyrighted image. Is there a similar non-copyrighted image that can be substituted?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with above. In my own personal experience, I switched directly to a 3/4 from a 1/4 with no in-betweens. This was challenging for me but gave me more time to practice with the spacing of the larger violin. At age 16 I got my LRSM (Licentiate of the Royal Schools of Music) in violin performance, so I guess I turned out ok?